# Looking for a monitor for my 2012 model iMac

Tags: imac, display

I know there are many of these types of questions, but the answers for the later models do not directly help with the newer iMac model that just came out in December 2012. I'm having a HUGE issue finding a second 24" monitor that my iMac doesn't have to calibrate and give me multiple blue screens once turning that second monitor on.

I've looked at this question and it's answers 
[iMac second monitor alternative](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52767/imac-second-monitor-alternative)

and a few more however I'm looking for an answer, hopfeully from another newer iMac owner.

There was a Gateway monitor on sale through the holidays however it gave me that unwanted 5 seconds of blue screen on my iMAc when I turned it o (every single time). So I took it back and I've used 2 older monitors from Asus (unfortunately, not my own but from friends) and they work no problem. So I set out to buy an Asus. However this Asus monitor I have hooked up to it now is worse and give me multiple blue screens that last longer than the first once it's turned on.

Is there an individual that has faced this before with their new 2012 iMac and did you find a monitor that just turned on normally (with no blue screen interruptions)?
I'm not looking for the cinema display, I'm not looking for that at this moment (although it is in my wish list for the end of the year, but after purchasing this new iMac and can't afford that right now. I'm just looking for an overall decent monitor I can work on when it comes to text documents, videos & surfing.)

I appreciate any help and hope that this is a valid question.

Comment: Are you talking about the brief "blue screens" when you add a monitor or change resolutions?  Or does it happen more frequently than that?

Comment: It's brief blue screens twice every time I turn my monitor on, which is about 4 or 5 times a day as I don't like having it on while I'm not using it. The prvious monitor at least only did it once and the older models so far don't do it at all. I'm back to borrowing a monitor from a friend but have to buy one soon as they need their monitor back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently added an LG FlatIron IPS234V LED monitor, 1920 x 1080, to my 2011 iMac, that I purchased from NewEgg for about $160.  It connects to the ThunderBolt port through a DVI cable and a MiniDisplayPort to DVI adapter, both from Monoprice, for about $16.

After inserting the MiniDisplayPort adapter in the port, and turning the monitor on, the image appears without any changes to the iMac display.  I am quite pleased with the combo so far, at what seems a reasonable cost. Windows can be dragged from one screen to the other.

I cannot say how this combo would work with a 2012 iMac.  The additional display space remains active even if the monitor is turned off, until the cable is disconnected from the ThunderBolt port.  This is disruptive for remote control, so I try to disconnect the cable before I leave the system.

I have seen the blue screens when I change the display resolution on either screen, but not otherwise.

Comment: Although I have a 2012 I will try this option. Thank you for your response, it's greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

About the only monitor you're pretty much guaranteed not to have a problem with are Apple's. They are a bit more expensive than the competition, but you get what you pay for.

Also, how often do you turn your monitor on, it doesn't seem like this is a big deal. I've always bought Dell monitors for my Macintosh desktops and have never had the problem you describe.

Comment: FWIW, I do see the blue screens when I wake up my 2012 rMBP with a 23" Apple Cinema Display attached via thunderbolt->DVI, so Apple-Apple is not guaranteed to avoid the issue. It never really bothered me though.

Comment: Hmm..interesting to know jalynn. That newer monitor bugged me so much, it was a good 5 seconds before I could start working again. I just don't see why it would work with some monitors and not with others. I like to turn my monitor off while I'm not using it (so I don't have distractions) which is about 4 or 5 times a day, so it's not the end of the world but it's kind of annoying. I was just hoping to find a new iMac user who's found a monitor that works. There is one out there, I know it!